# Apache POI. Как найти и подключить отсутствующие классы HWPF, XWPF, XSSF,

Tags: excel, intellij-idea, maven, ms-word, apache-poi

Пытаюсь начать работу с библиотекой Apache POI. Во многих обзорах, а самое главное в самой документации Apache POI есть описание классов XWPF и XSSF для работы c .docx и .xlsx файлами соответственно. Но проблема в том, что если импортировать библиотеку через Maven или скачивать её с сайта, то этих классов нет там как таковых и я не могу понять где их найти и как их подключить к проекту, чтобы начать работу с ними.
В Maven использую такую зависимость:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

При подключении этой библиотеки присутствуют только эти пакеты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь видно, что есть папка с классами для работы с файлами формата .xls, а именно HSSF, а вот всего остального что я описал выше нет в принципе, нет даже классов для работы с файлами формата .doc. Если скачивать архив файлов напрямую с сайта, то там ровно тоже самое. В общем хочется узнать почему нет этих классов, можно ли их найти и как их подключить к проекту.